# Rails SQL injection vulnerability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-injection

Does using `Model.find(params[:id])` can lead to sql injection vulnerability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it can't. Quote from Guides (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection):

> Ruby on Rails has a built-in filter for special SQL characters, which will escape ' , " , NULL character and line breaks. Using Model.find(id) or Model.find_by_some thing(something) automatically applies this countermeasure.

BTW you probably meant `Model.find(params[:id])` or `Model.find_by(id: params[:id])`, `Model.find(id: params[:id])` makes no sense.